# Stored Procedure that takes two inputs STORE CODE and EMPLOYEE CODE and displays message if corresponding columns match

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms

Like question said, I have to create a stored procedure in SQL that takes two parameters, a store code and an employee code (I have a table EMPLOYEE that has columns STORE_CODE and EMP_CODE) and I need to print a message that tells if that employee works in that specific store or not.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE EmployeeVerify @STORE_CODE int, @EMP_CODE int
AS
DECLARE @store int
SELECT @store = STORE_CODE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE STORE_CODE = @STORE_CODE

DECLARE @emp int
SELECT @emp = EMP_CODE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_CODE = @EMP_CODE

IF @emp != @store
BEGIN
PRINT 'EMPLOYEE DOES NOT WORK AT THIS STORE'
END

ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'EMPLOYEE WORKS AT THIS STORE'
END
```

I tested this to see with an employee code 1 that should match store code 3, yet it says employee does not work at this store. Not sure how to go about connecting the inputs with the actual columns.

[image: Screenshot of sample data. each employee has an EMPLOYEE CODE and depending on what store they work in they have a STORE CODE that corresponds to them.]
SH

Comment: You don't make any correlation between `store_code` and `employee`, share your tables' schema and sample data.

Comment: @Stu I added a screenshot of sample data. I have table EMPLOYEE with employee information. Two columns I am working with are EMP_CODE which is assigned to each employee, and this correlates to a STORE_CODE which is the store that employee works in. Hence why I need to see if the EMP_CODE and STORE_CODE match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data image it looks like you just need a simple `exists` check

```
if exists (
    select *
    from employee 
    where emp_code = @emp_code and store_code = @store_code
)
  print 'employee works at store'
else
  print 'employee does not work at store'
```